# Javascript Observer pattern can not access private property

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, observer-pattern

The following code below is javascript obeserver pattern, but when it execute "subject.subscribeObserver(observer1);", error occurs that "can not read property push of undefined", it seems that I can not access subject.observers. Why does this happen? In subscribeObserver function I keep this.observers referrence, but subject instance still not access to it. When I use prototype pattern but not return object pattern it works,that is really puzzle me.

```
var Subject = function() {
        this.observers = [];

        return {
            subscribeObserver: function(observer) {
                console.log(this);
                this.observers.push(observer);
            },
            unsubscribeObserver: function(observer) {
                var index = this.observers.indexOf(observer);
                if (index > -1) {
                    this.observers.splice(index, 1);
                }
            },
            notifyObserver: function(observer) {
                var index = this.observers.indexOf(observer);
                if (index > -1) {
                    this.observers[index].notify(index);
                }
            },
            notifyAllObservers: function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < this.observers.length; i++) {
                    this.observers[i].notify(i);
                };
            }
        };
    };

    var Observer = function() {
        return {
            notify: function(index) {
                console.log("Observer " + index + " is notified!");
            }
        }
    }

    var subject = new Subject();

    var observer1 = new Observer();
    var observer2 = new Observer();
    var observer3 = new Observer();
    var observer4 = new Observer();

    subject.subscribeObserver(observer1);
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I […] not return object […] it works, that is really puzzle me.

Well yes, you are returning a new object from your constructor. Which means the `this` object (that you stored the `.observers` property on) is completely forgotten about. In the `subject.subscribeObserver()` call, the `this` in the method refers to `subject`, i.e. the returned object. You should be able to see that from the `console.log(this)` - the logged object is the one with the methods, but no array.

You *could* put the array on the returned object:

```
function Subject() {
    return {
        observers: [],
        subscribeObserver(observer) {
            …
        },
        …
    };
}
```

but I would recommend to just use the prototype pattern with all its benefits.